# How to view contents of extended control registers in GDB?

Tags: gdb, x86-64

**Is there a way to view the contents of the x86-64 extended control registers? In particular, I'd like the values in `XCR0`.**

- `info all-registers` doesn't provide the control registers in the displayed registers.
- `info register xcr0` results in a "Invalid register 'xcr0'" error message.
- `p $xcr0` results in "$1 = void".

The GDB documentation, [10.13, "Registers"](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html) doesn't provide any other ways to view register contents, and I couldn't find a reference to the extended control registers generally in the documentation.

Comment: May I ask if you happen to be debugging a QEMU session with GDB?

Comment: @MichaelPetch no. I am debugging a program running natively on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Linux control registers aren't directly available to user code running at ring 3 (Linux user mode) so they can't be directly queried by the debugger.

Comment: @MichaelPetch if you expound that comment a bit and post it as an answer, I'll accept it.